# lottery generator won't shuffle

Tags: c

I need to make lottery generator. (randomly show 5 numbers from 1-45)
I tried as below but it would show the same 5 numbers over and over and would not shuffle.
anyone please tell me what's wrong and how I can make the code shuffle. 
thank you:)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int lotto_gen()
{
    int ball = 1 + rand() % 45;
    return ball;
}
void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
    int r;
    r = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = r;
}
void shuffle(int* arr, int size)
{
    int i,r;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        r = rand() % (size - i) + i;
        swap(arr + i, arr + r);
    }
}
int main (void)
{
    int i,j;
    int lotto[45] = { 0 };
    int size = sizeof(lotto) / sizeof(lotto[0]);
    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        lotto[i]=lotto_gen();
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {

        printf("[");
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", lotto[i]);
        }
        printf("]\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the numbers would change when you print them? They change when you assign them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print display the values from the same index in each loop :

```
 for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{

    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", lotto[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

}
```

Your "j" index is not used here, so you display the value from index [0, 6[ 10 times.
You need to use the "j" index to display all values from "lotto".

But other observation. Your lotto array size is 45 but you only filled the first 10 values.

A correction could be :

```
int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    int lotto[45] = { 0 };
    int size = sizeof(lotto) / sizeof(lotto[0]);
    srand(time(0));

    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            lotto[i + (j * 5)] = lotto_gen();
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {

        printf("[");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", lotto[i+(j*5)]);
        }
        printf("]\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Take care of the fix about 6 modified to 5 and 10 to 9, else you'll be out of the array bounds and you'll display 6 values instead of 5 in each loop.
And use const variable for define array size and for bounds.

With my correction, the output is :

```
[2 3 26 34 13 ]
[35 19 7 17 44 ]
[17 45 23 3 16 ]
[18 9 36 45 43 ]
[17 2 22 17 18 ]
[8 28 13 33 12 ]
[17 22 30 5 19 ]
[19 11 1 28 45 ]
[21 21 18 28 20 ]
```